# deleting the parent (primary) values when deleting the inline value django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

When I am trying to delete the values in inlines using Django admin, the primary key objects are deleting. Please help in solving my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details when asking questions. You can give your model structure and tell when I do this, this is happening.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @Yamanasanthoshkumar that is exactly my answer, if it helped please accept it instead of writing it in the comments.

Comment: @Yamanasanthoshkumar you cannot just use someone else answer and put it in the comment, good practice is to accept helpful answers in order to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your goal since the question is a bit vague. But if you are using the default `Delete` button in the bottom left corner, your telling Django to delete the *parent* model which represent the top level model. To only delete data of the object in the inline section, you must use the check-box in top right corner of the inline and then use one of the save button of the model.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove the default "Delete" button, I don't think there is any easy way to this. What I'd recommend is to use permission.

You could try this code:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        #Disable delete
        return False
```

Note that I can't test it, it is just to give an idea of what is available to you.

Comment: yes , my question is a bit vague ..i understand the difference between delete option in the left side corner and delete with check box in the right corner  along with save button...Thanks a lot..

Comment: Why do you want to delete it ?

Comment: Actually the delete option is confusing to staff users ..instead of using save button , uses delete button. So that the parent object also deleting, in the inline process....